# Dynamically deleting the column from multidimensional array of object value

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to delete the column from multidimensional array of objects,
below is the multidimensional array of objects and  the code I have tried: -

```js
const array1 = [
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ]
];

array1.map((a, i) => {
  a.splice(2, 1);
  console.log(a)
  return a;
});

console.log(array1);
```

In the above array i want to remove column second and fourth column as they are same value,

The above logic i found, but here instead of 2 i want to pass index dynamically , i have tried lot combinations it dint work, also i tried to pass array1 index but not deleting correct column.

If i pass index as dynamically then in the array if the column is repeated it will delete automatically.

Below is the expected output:-

```js
result = [
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },

    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },

  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },

    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },

  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },

    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },

  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },

    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },

  ],
];
```

here is below image of array, marked one needs to be deleted:

[image]

Comment: No need for `map` if you want to edit an array. Just use forEach

Comment: What do you mean by "remove 2nd and 4th column as they are same value" ??? What is expected output?

Comment: @mplungjan i want to delete the column dynamically, the above is the example where in each sub array contains  delete type == label and  id: 13995, which i want to delete from parent array

Comment: From the array you are given, I understand that you are trying to delete item which has id 13998. Is that correct?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti yes trying to delete id - 13998 and id 13940

Comment: @Codenewbie 
[[1],[2],[3],[4]],
[[a],[2],[3],[b]]  
this is the result i need  
[[1],[4]],
[[a],[b]]

Comment: please could you add expected o/p , it would be easy for readers , thanks

Comment: @Codenewbie added the expected result

Comment: `as they are same value` what is the same value? is that `label`?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti id is same

Comment: @vinuta does my answer help's achieving the expected result ? please could you check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try like below

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 24, 'c'],
  ['a', 2, 3, 'b', 24, 'd']
];
let resultArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));

let tempArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    tempArr.push(arr[j][i]);
  }
  if (tempArr.every(item => item === tempArr[0])) {
    let index = resultArr[0].findIndex(p => p === tempArr[0]);
    resultArr = resultArr.map(val => {
      val.splice(index, 1);
      return val;
    });
  }
  tempArr = [];
}

console.log(resultArr);
```

So, based on the above logic the original answer will be below

```js
const array1 = [
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ]
];

let resultArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array1));

let tempArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array1[0].length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
    tempArr.push(array1[j][i]);
  }
  if (tempArr.every(item => item.type === tempArr[0].type && item.type === 'label')) {
    let index = resultArr[0].findIndex(p => p.id === tempArr[0].id);
    resultArr = resultArr.map(val => {
      val.splice(index, 1);
      return val;
    });
  }
  tempArr = [];
}

console.log(resultArr);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219784/discussion-on-answer-by-sivakumar-tadisetti-dynamically-deleting-the-column-from).

Answer (score 1):

```
    [
        { id: 1 },
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 3 },
        { id: 4 },
    ],
    [
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 2 },
        { id: 3 },
        { id: 5 },
    ],
]

function createNewArray(arr, n) {
    const newArr = [];
    arr.forEach(element => {
        newArr.push(element[n])
    });
    return newArr;
}

function getResult() {
    const tempArray = [];
    
    for (let index = 0; index < origin[0].length; index++){
        const newArray = createNewArray(origin, index).map(e => e.id);
        
        if ([...new Set(newArray)].length > 1) {
            tempArray.push(newArray);
        }
    }
    
    let result = Array(tempArray[0].length).fill([]);
    
    return result.map((item, index) => tempArray.map(e => e[index]));
}

console.log('result', getResult());
```

Comment: const settings = {
 0: [13998, 13940], //
 1: [13998] //
};
How to get these id from array and pass to settings, in my case i ll not be knowing which id need to pass, i need to loop and if the column for same id then i ll delete the column

Comment: do you need to remove duplicates?

Comment: are you sure there is no mistakes you wrote above: [[1],[2],[3],[4]], [[2],[2],[3],[5]] -->  [[2],[4]], [[2],[5]].

I think you mean that output should be [[1],[4]], [[2],[5]]

Comment: yes the output should be [[1],[4]], [[2],[5]] .. because as you see 2 is repeated in both the array, as well as 3, i just want to deleted respected column

Comment: each array of your array has the same length?

Comment: here the answer should be [ [ 1, 4 ], [ 2, 5 ] ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219729/discussion-between-vinuta-and-dmitry-grinko).

Comment: Updated my answer. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
const removeCol = (table, colIndex) => {
  table.forEach(row => row.splice(colIndex, 1))  
}
removeCol(array1, 0); // To remove column 0 (0-indexed)
removeCol(array1, 1); // To remove column 1 (0-indexed)
```

Comment: but passing 0,1 wont work in my case because i have multiple arrays

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but to get result as expected :

1. Filter `id's` of two `13993`,`13998`
2. check the `id` and modify value accordingly

```js
const array1 = [
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "checkbox",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ],
  [{
      checked: false,
      id: 13993,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13995,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13998,
      type: "label",
    },
    {
      checked: false,
      id: 13940,
      type: "label",
    },
  ]
];

let filteredArray = array1.map(x=>x.filter(v=>v.id==13993||v.id==13998)) // 1st step
let result = filteredArray.map(x=>x.filter(v=>v.id==13993?v.type="checkbox":v.type="label")) // 2nd step

//2nd step i guess can be done in much efficient way

console.log(result)
```

Comment: here if i have id known then it ll work for example: 13998 is know id i can pass it v.id==13993||v.id==13998 --> here but if the id is not known, then what do  i need to pass and compare like, v.id === v.id then further thing.

Comment: but for the expected o/p there must be a logic to be dynamic .... i couldn't find any